# @Inject não funciona dentro de classe anotada @Scheduled

Tags: java

Estou criando uma classe usando deltaspike e quartz, usando @scheduled. Nessa classe injeto um bean CDI, que é uma classe de serviço. Optei por usar o deltaspike porque ele controla o contexto do CDI dentro das classes que utilizam quartz. O bean, porém, não é injetado, ficando nulo. No console não é disparada nenhuma exceção. O código execute aparenta nem ser chamado. Mas tirando todo o código do método, removendo @Inject e deixando somente as chamadas do log, funciona perfeitamente. O que pode estar faltando configurar para que a injeção de dependência funcione? Segue código.

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
public class NotificacaoAgendaJob implements Job {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("br.com.nutrierp.scheduler");

    @Inject
    AgendaService agendaService;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            logger.info("Iniciando Job...");
            List<Agenda> agendas = agendaService.todasAgendasDoSistema();

            for (Agenda agenda : agendas) {
                LocalDateTime dataAgendada = agenda.getDataInicial();
                LocalDateTime dataAtual = LocalDateTime.now();
                Duration intervalo = Duration.between(dataAtual, dataAgendada);

                if (intervalo.toHours() <= 24 && intervalo.toHours() > 0) {
                    agendaService.enviarEmailDeNotificacao(agenda);
                }
            }
            logger.info("Finalizando Job...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cadê o resto do codigo, o codigo do web.xml, o do springContext.xml?

Comment: Weslley, na documentação do deltaspike não há referência sobre configurações adicionais no web.xml, nem configurações necessárias no quartz.proprties. de fato, sem incluir @Inject e retirar o código que usa o objeto injetado, o método execute é executado. Minha aplicação não usa spring, somente CDI

Comment: E cade a classe AgendaService ? Vc adicionou o @Named ?

Comment: Normalmente para um dependencia ser criada, vc adiciona o @named, acho que a classe NotificacaoAgendaJob  náo é um bean por isso ela nao carrega o AgendaService

Answer (score 0):

Após ler novamente a documentação do deltaspike, verifiquei que os beans não são injetados porque a classe anotada  com @scheduled é instanciada fora do contexto do CDI. Usei um CDIServiceLocator.

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "0 0 2 1/1 * ?")
public class NotificacaoAgendaJob implements Job {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NotificacaoAgendaJob.class.getName());

    SistemaService sistemaService;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        try {
            sistemaService = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(SistemaService.class);

            logger.info("Iniciando Job...");
            List<Agenda> agendas = sistemaService.todasAgendasDoSistema();

            for (Agenda agenda : agendas) {
                LocalDate dataAgendada = agenda.getDataInicial().toLocalDate();
                LocalDate dataAtual = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
                long intervalo = dataAgendada.toEpochDay() - dataAtual.toEpochDay();

                if (intervalo == 1) {
                    sistemaService.enviarEmailDeNotificacao(agenda);
                    logger.info("Enviando e-mail para " + agenda.getPaciente().getEmail());
                }
            }
            logger.info("Finalizando Job...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

CDIServiceLocator

```
public class CDIServiceLocator {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {

        BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();

        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm.getBeans(clazz).iterator().next();
        CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
        T targetBean = (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx);

        return targetBean;
    }

}
```

Saída no console

```
mar 08, 2018 9:44:00 PM br.com.nutrierp.scheduler.NotificacaoAgendaJob execute
INFORMAÇÕES: Iniciando Job...
Hibernate: select agenda0_.id as id1_0_, agenda0_.data_final as data_fin2_0_, agenda0_.data_inicial as data_ini3_0_, agenda0_.descricao as descrica4_0_, agenda0_.notificacao_agenda as notifica5_0_, agenda0_.notificacao_enviada_ao_agendar as notifica6_0_, agenda0_.notificacao_enviada_um_dia_antes as notifica7_0_, agenda0_.paciente_id as pacient10_0_, agenda0_.situacao as situacao8_0_, agenda0_.tipo as tipo9_0_, agenda0_.utilizador_id as utiliza11_0_ from agendas agenda0_ order by agenda0_.data_inicial desc
mar 08, 2018 9:44:07 PM br.com.nutrierp.scheduler.NotificacaoAgendaJob execute
INFORMAÇÕES: Enviando e-mail para xxxxxx@gmail.com
mar 08, 2018 9:44:15 PM br.com.nutrierp.scheduler.NotificacaoAgendaJob execute
INFORMAÇÕES: Enviando e-mail para xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
mar 08, 2018 9:44:22 PM br.com.nutrierp.scheduler.NotificacaoAgendaJob execute
INFORMAÇÕES: Enviando e-mail para xxxxxxx@hotmail.com
mar 08, 2018 9:44:22 PM br.com.nutrierp.scheduler.NotificacaoAgendaJob execute
INFORMAÇÕES: Finalizando Job...
```

Usando esse CDIServiceLocator, todas as dependências, de todas as classes envolvidas, inclusive entity managers, serão resolvidas.